# LUA_HOOKRET not working when function is called inside return

Tags: lua, lua-api

I am trying to setup a small profiler and in consequence I need to record every time the program enters and leaves a function.
The problem is that it doesn't work when the function called is inside a 'return' (eg. return f() ).

For instance in the code below, when executing the code 'missing_call_and_ret' we can only see the call to g (but not f) and we can't see the exit of f and g.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work ?
I'm using lua 5.4.6

This code reproduce the problem:

```
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void profile_hook(lua_State *L, lua_Debug *ar) {
  if (!lua_getinfo(L, "Sn", ar)) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  switch (ar->event) {
  case LUA_HOOKCALL:
    printf("Enter %s %s:%d\n", ar->name, ar->short_src, ar->linedefined);
    break;
  case LUA_HOOKRET:
    printf("Leave %s %s:%d\n", ar->name, ar->short_src, ar->linedefined);
    break;
  }
}

void main() {
  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);
  lua_sethook(L, profile_hook, LUA_MASKCALL | LUA_MASKRET, 0);
  const char *okay_ret = "function f() return 7 end\n"
                         "function g() local v=f() return v end\n"
                         "print(g())\n";

  const char *missing_call_and_ret = "function f() return 7 end\n"
                                     "function g() return f() end\n"
                                     "print(g())\n";

  printf("Okay ret:\n");
  if (luaL_dostring(L, okay_ret) != LUA_OK) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("\nMissing call and ret:\n");
  if (luaL_dostring(L, missing_call_and_ret) != LUA_OK) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return f()` is a tail call, it is explained in [section 3.4.10](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.4.10):

> A call of the form return functioncall not in the scope of a to-be-closed variable is called a tail call. Lua implements proper tail calls (or proper tail recursion): In a tail call, the called function reuses the stack entry of the calling function. Therefore, there is no limit on the number of nested tail calls that a program can execute. However, a tail call **erases any debug information about the calling function**.

This mechanism of Lua can avoid some stack overflow problems, but the disadvantage is that Lua will remove debugging informations.

You need to use `LUA_HOOKTAILCALL` to catch the event. There is also a `istailcall` property in `lua_Debug` that can help you find the corresponding return event (flag `t` needs to be specified).